# Remove GNOME 40 and install GNOME 3X instead?

Tags: gnome, desktop-environments, ubuntu-gnome

I am on ubuntu 21.10 (currently 22.04). and i dont like the UI that gnome 40 has on ubuntu. i personally preferred the look of the previous versions (such as 21.04) as it looked more in place with Ubuntu's GUI. If its not possible, is it at least possible to make it "**feel**" like gnome 3 or in other words, earlier versions of ubuntu which included GNOME? I really dont like the new UI of gnome 40 or new ubuntu versions with it in general.

Comment: You can't downgrade GNOME. Either stick to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (which still uses GNOME3), or switch to MATE/XFCE/KDE, whose developers do not reinvent their interface every few years.

Comment: my current computer does not support 20.04 LTS due to drivers. i cant use internet drivers with it. so i am essentially stuck to using 21.04+. I would use 21.04 but i dont want to use an EOL operating system.

Comment: Try another DE, then.

Comment: I would do that but i am really used to GNOME. as i mentioned as well, is it possible to make GNOME 40 feel like gnome 3?

Comment: I found this, but I don't know if it works. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=P0i4PQND0mk

Comment: This works perfectly without ubuntu's panel turned on... However with the dock on its pretty buggy... i wish i could use the dock but as long as it looks like gnome 3 i'm fine!

Comment: You mention your machine cannot use 20.04 due to *drivers* but have given no specifics... Are you sure?  Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the HWE kernel stack is now using the same kernel as found in Ubuntu 21.10 (ie. 5.13) meaning it's got the same *kernel modules* which are commonly know as *drivers*. Are you sure you can't use 20.04 LTS?   *Ubuntu LTS releases have at least two kernel stack choices; with OEM options as well on some hardware* https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: I used gnome 3 on my old computer, this is my new computer which i got near the end of last year. this one does not support 20.04 LTS like my previous HP laptop, my new pc btw is an acer swift 3 sf-314-43 (Ryzen 3 5300U,and 8gb of ram). edit 2, ubuntu 21.10 comes with kernel 5.15.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu?  Ubuntu 21.10's default kernel is 5.13 and not 5.15.  Please provide specifics as to your OS & release as 5.15 is **not** the *generic* kernel of Ubuntu 21.10.   Please provide `uname -r` & `lsb_release -a` in your question as your comment details match a non-Ubuntu (unless using OEM kernel which if so, may work with Ubuntu 20.04.4 if you tried it!)

Comment: Well i am using 22.04's lts version. I said 21.10 as at the moment both operating systems dont have much differences ATM... I personally did not like 21.10 due to performance issues. when i tried zorin on a usb it did not work so with that said i don't really think ubuntu 20.04 would work either, as zorin os 16 is based on 20.04 LTS.

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 doesn't yet exist; it's currently the *development* release Ubuntu *jammy* and remains that until it reaches RC state which isn't expected until after 14 April 2022, and isn't on-topic here until release on 21 April 2022.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-schedule/23906  Please refer https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic.  For support issues with Ubuntu *jammy* you'll need to use a #ubuntu-next or #ubuntu+1 site (IRC, UF etc)

Comment: Zorin OS is **not** Ubuntu LTS; does not have the multiple installers available for use (*chosen by ISO downloaded and used*), nor choice of kernel stack choices etc...  If you don't know, you should **not** make assumptions, and be specific; however you're off-topic here - please read prior comment.

Comment: ah right, true... also i see that you mentioned 20.04.4 on your post. is that even released yet???? Ubuntu's download page still shows 20.04.3...

Comment: Are you sure about the drivers? If it's kernel drivers, then you need to install the HWE kernel that will give you access to the newer kernel on 20.04.

Comment: I did not have drivers on 20.04.3. so i'm currently flashing ubuntu 20.04.4 to my flash drive. i dont really care about my files as i never store essential things on my computer. my important files go onto my windows 7 desktop with a 1 TB hard drive.

Comment: Just got 20.04.4 and my drivers seem to be working! seems like an issue with the old 20.04 version... and i got good GNOME 3 back, hell yeah.

Comment: FYI:  Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS isn't planned to release until 24 February 2022 UTC (ie. *later today for most; early tomorrow/25th my local time*); it uses the kernel from Ubuntu 21.10 and thus it's kernel modules (known as *drivers*), which have been available for ~two weeks on installed 20.04 system...  Officially out no, but teams need to mark "*ready*" (*requests for this have occurred*), mirrors get time to *sync* it first etc, before release gets authorized & official release announcements sent.  https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/focal-fossa-20-04-4-lts-point-release-status-tracking/26490

Comment: its already the 24th here lol

Answer (score 4):

You cannot downgrade Gnome on Ubuntu without the technical skills required to download source code and compile an earlier version including all earlier dependencies on your Linux system, which, after such operation, cannot anymore be called an Ubuntu system.

Gnome 40 did, apart from the visual change in horizontal layout of workspaces instead of vertical, not fundamentally change the workflow. You did not indicate what bothers you, but if that is the issue, the Gnome Shell extension  [Vertical overview by Ralthuis](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/4144/vertical-overview/) can bring back the vertical layout.